# Holo Colors on pre Holo Devices?

Tags: android

I am using Keyboardsurfer's Crouton class for Android. It uses the Holo Colors as Background Color (android.R.color.holo_red_light).

Now those colors only get shown on Holo Themed Devices. On the older ones it's shown as grey.

I now want to know if there is any way of getting those colors to the old devices too to use them?

Comment: The issue has been resolved. Crouton now works on pre holo devices as well.

Comment: Saw it when I updated to the newest version. Thanks alot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the Color values from `<android-sdk-path>/platforms/android-16/data/res/values/colors.xml` to your own `colors.xml` file - `<project-dir>/res/values/colors.xml`.

Now use the values as Background color `(R.color.holo_red_light)`.

`<android-sdk-path>` is you android-sdk direcotry path.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the colors here: http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html (mouseover to see the hex code). Save the colors you need in your colors.xml file at values. 
Than you can define your own Crouton styles using the color id's of the colors you saved (R.color.xxx).